# Browser Plugin to fill a large html form with test data

Tags: firefox, testing, web-applications, web, mozilla

In one of the flows in a java web application, I have a form page which captures around 50 odd fields. Now to test a code change in the last page in this flow I have to fill almost all the fields in all the pages that come before it (approximately around 75 fields). This takes a lot of effort in creating the test data and testing the change

Most of the time I enter the same data in these fields for testing. Any suggestion to automate this, something like a firefox plugin which could save the form data within the browser and populate it again the next time i want to ?

I tried searching over the internet but I could only find [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which isn't what I need exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium or iMacros for Firefox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/.